# Hume's analogy to prove that the soul is mortal

Tags: hume, souls

Passage from "The immortality of the soul" by David Hume

> Where any two items x and y are so closely connected that all alterations we have ever seen in x are accompanied by corresponding alterations in y, we ought to conclude—by all the rules of analogy—that when x undergoes still greater alterations, so that it is totally dissolved, a total dissolution of y will follow.

How is that scientific? Does a strong correlation between two things imply that both things are *always* connected?

Comment: Is "common sense" view about the mechanism of the world and is at the core of Hume's philosophy of cause and induction : we "perceive" strong correlations and we assume that they are the product of rules (laws of nature) that necessarily links the correlated facts.

Comment: a necessity which we cannot prove i presume since it is just an assumption. so Hume's philosophy is kind of axiomatic?

Comment: "axiomatic" ? Every philosophy try to support some "general principles" usimg argument. Very few philosophers (see Spinoza) try to deduce them from axioms.

Comment: "we "perceive" strong correlations and we assume that they are the product of rules (laws of nature) that necessarily links the correlated facts." that's axiomatic as i see it

Comment: A simple organic chemistry lab experiment might disprove that statement.

Comment: He sets up a straw-man and knocks it down. His argument seems to hold for x and y if they are related as he specifies, which suggests he has an incorrect idea of the soul. His argument seems more sound than his assumptions.

Comment: The quoted passage is not mathematically or scientifically accurate. If y = ax + b (a & b are constants), then changes in x are accompanied by corresponding chages in y (delta y = a*delta x), but y is not 0 when x is 0. This is the equation of numerous scientific processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to PSE.

To begin, Hume does not offer this argument from analogy as a 'proof'  but only as 'strong'. Also he has in mind not a correlation merely 'strong' (or frequent) but a correlation exceptionless in experience: 'all alterations which we have ever seen in the one, are attended with proportionable alterations in the other'.

More than that, Hume is a sceptic. 'The analogy from nature' assumes not in fact his own position but that of those who believe in the uniformity of a law-governed, causally determined nature. The analogy is pressed on those who hold this view. Hume himself, in his sceptical critique of induction, takes no such view of nature - as Enquiry concerning Human Understanding, IV.14-23 makes plain.

Comment: Why would he target a specific audience despite potential criticism? Was he proving a point that I missed?

Comment: Hume is assuming a position which he believed was endorsed by science and common sense. He has in mind not so much a specific audience - or readership - as  the entire generality of humankind. Hume is arguing from premises he believes to be false and drawing out consequences that, given *their* position, science and common sense ought to accept.